# Does a Silverlight share the HTTP connection of its host

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, video

Does a Silverlight video player share the HTTP connection with its host?

Here is the scenario: a web site is password protected. The web page contains a Silverlight control with a video player. The video player plays a video from the same web site. Will the credentials from the web browser be used by the video player? I use MediaElement.Source to specify where the video is coming from.

If not, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on the way it communicates with the server... for example the `webrequest` class can be set to use `BrowserHTTP` or `ClientHTTP`...

`BrowserHTTP` uses the browser's HTTP implementation including Referer, Cookies etc.

`ClientHTTP` allows you to manage HTTP setting like Cookies manually...

Using `MediaElement.SetSource` you can leverage whatever connection you please (`BrowserHTTP` / `ClientHTPP`) with you specific settings (including `Authorization` header / `Cookies` etc.) as log as that connection provides a `Stream` interface for the content...

Further details see

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.browser.webrequestcreator.browserhttp%28v=vs.95%29.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.browser.webrequestcreator.clienthttp%28v=vs.95%29.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838250%28v=vs.95%29.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190669%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Comment: I communicate using MediaElement.Source. Is it Browser or Client HTTP

Comment: see my addition about `MediaElement.SetSource` - this gives you the option to choose between `BrowserHTPP` / `ClientHTTP`...